# Device can't communicate with a specific device through sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, network-programming

I have three devices connected to a router (a jetson, a raspberry pi and a mac). All three devices can ping each other and ssh just fine. However, when I try to communicate via sockets with the code outlined in this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/, the mac cannot connect to the jetson. The jetson is fine in communicating with the other device.

The same issue occurred when using sockets through SFML.

Here's the socket code if it helps:

Server:

```
cout << "Launching remote joystick communications link..." << endl;
server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt));

address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = 2223;

bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address));
listen(server_fd, 3);

cout << "Waiting for joystick client..."  << endl;
new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
```

Client:

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
int sock = 0, valread;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(2223);

inet_pton(AF_INET, IP_ADDR, &serv_addr.sin_addr);
```

Comment: You don't do any error checking. If you check for errors they should tell you what is going wrong with the connection. If you detect an error, `std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';`.